# Transform prevents element from centering

Tags: html, css, flexbox, transform

Why is the sun not centered inside the green square? `justify-content: center` causes distortions.

```css
/* Sun Icon */
.sunIcon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border: Red solid 2px;
}

.allCircles {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: green solid 2px;
}

.circleBoxes {
  position: absolute;
  border: yellow solid 1px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.circles {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bgCircle {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.halfCircle {
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 100px 0 0 100px;
  transform-origin: right;
}

/* First Circle */
.circle1 > .halfCircle {
  background: #ff5500;
  transform: rotate(225deg) scale(3.8, 3.8);
  z-index: 2;
}

.circle1 > .bgCircle {
  transform: scale(3.8, 3.8);
  background: #ff7900;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Second Circle */
.circle2 > .halfCircle {
  background: #ff7900;
  transform: rotate(180deg) scale(2.8, 2.8);
  z-index: 4;
}

.circle2 > .bgCircle {
  transform: scale(2.8, 2.8);
  background: #ff9700;
  z-index: 3;
}

/* Third Circle */
.circle3 > .halfCircle {
  background: #ffaa00;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1.6, 1.6);
  z-index: 6;
}

.circle3 > .bgCircle {
  transform: scale(1.6, 1.6);
  background: #ff9700;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
    <div class="sunIcon">
        <div class='allCircles'>
            <div class="circle1 circleBoxes">
                <div class="halfCircle circles"></div>
                <div class="bgCircle circles"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="circle2 circleBoxes">
                <div class="halfCircle circles"></div>
                <div class="bgCircle circles"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="circle3 circleBoxes">
                <div class="halfCircle circles"></div>
                <div class="bgCircle circles"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your content is not aligning because of the absolute positioning used on the parent `.circleBoxes`. Assuming this is a must for the `transform` to work as intended. One solution would be to remove the fixed height and width on `.allCircles` and use padding instead. See the CSS changes I made below.

```css
/* Sun Icon */

.sunIcon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border: Red solid 2px;
}

.allCircles {
  padding: 25px 33px 25px 25px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: green solid 2px;
}

.circleBoxes {
  position: absolute;
  border: yellow solid 1px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.circles {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bgCircle {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.halfCircle {
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 100px 0 0 100px;
  transform-origin: right;
}


/* First Circle */

.circle1>.halfCircle {
  background: #ff5500;
  transform: rotate(225deg) scale(3.8, 3.8);
  z-index: 2;
}

.circle1>.bgCircle {
  transform: scale(3.8, 3.8);
  background: #ff7900;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Second Circle */

.circle2>.halfCircle {
  background: #ff7900;
  transform: rotate(180deg) scale(2.8, 2.8);
  z-index: 4;
}

.circle2>.bgCircle {
  transform: scale(2.8, 2.8);
  background: #ff9700;
  z-index: 3;
}


/* Third Circle */

.circle3>.halfCircle {
  background: #ffaa00;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1.6, 1.6);
  z-index: 6;
}

.circle3>.bgCircle {
  transform: scale(1.6, 1.6);
  background: #ff9700;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="sunIcon">
  <div class='allCircles'>
    <div class="circle1 circleBoxes">
      <div class="halfCircle circles"></div>
      <div class="bgCircle circles"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="circle2 circleBoxes">
      <div class="halfCircle circles"></div>
      <div class="bgCircle circles"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="circle3 circleBoxes">
      <div class="halfCircle circles"></div>
      <div class="bgCircle circles"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is pixel calculation needed for `padding`? Can't we specify the center regardless of the final position obtained with `transform`?

Comment: @Dပとк No, because the each circle with the transformation also has the class with the position absolute. As mentioned in answer, the position absolute is the root to why it’s not centering.

Comment: There must be some other solution besides `svg` or pixel computation, maybe the `transform` alternative is needed.